# Why does this link match this regex?

Tags: regex

This regex:

```
(youtube.com|youtu.be).*(v=)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)
```

Should match this string:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PnqCS4Lvy5E
```

It also successfully matches this string:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=
```

Which is wrong. How do I make sure that link does have the string after v= ? (can't use dollar sign, since `v` can be anywhere in the link)

Comment: The youtube video ID `(v)` is always 11 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `+` instead of `*` and use `^$` to indicate start and end of a string:

`^https?:\/\/www\.(youtube.com|youtu.be).*(v=)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$`

**or**, to specify a minimum number of characters after `v=`, do:

`^https?:\/\/www\.(youtube.com|youtu.be).*(v=)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,})$    // here 3 is the minimum numbers of accepted chars in the string`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/rP1lN3

Comment: Modified it to accept Youtube/Vimeo links. + Optional WWW: `https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?(((youtube.com|youtu.be).*(v=)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,}))|(vimeo.com).*([0-9]{3,}))`